# Consulta left join multitabla llamando varios campos de la segunda tabla

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

Estoy haciendo una consulta con dos tablas, la idea es que a través del id_customer que comparten la primera tabla (Linking_clients) y la segunda tabla (customer)" se pueda acceder a multiples campos en una misma consulta de la segunda tabla; campos que no existen en la primera tabla "validation_code", "identity_document_type_id", etc... Como verán en las tablas en la parte inferior, se darán cuenta que estos campos no existen en la primera tabla, por lo que la única forma que tengo para acceder a estos es que la consulta identifique el id_customer de ambas tablas y me llame los datos en una lista. Agradezco cualquier ayuda y/o explicación que me puedan prestar., es un poco redundante, pero espero a ver sido especifica.

La consulta debería llamar los datos de la tabla Linking_clients y adicional consultar de acuerdo al customer_id de  esta tabla coincidir con el customer_id de la tabla "customer" y llamar los campos "validation_code", "identity_document_number", "identity_document_type_id", etc.

Tabla Numero 1

```html
CREATE TABLE `oc_customer` (
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customer_group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `identity_document_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `identity_document_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `validation_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `redirect_mail` varchar(96) NOT NULL,
  `customer_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(96) NOT NULL,
  `telephone` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `image_profile` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `fax` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `cart` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `wishlist` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `newsletter` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `address_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `custom_field` text NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `safe` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `token` text NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Tabla Nº 2

```html
CREATE TABLE `oc_linking_clients (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `registration_date` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `registration_time` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_by_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `update_date` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `update_time` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `updated_by_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `family_group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;
```

Consulta que intento realizar... pero que claramente no funciona

```
$sql = "SELECT lc.id as id, 
        lc.registration_date as registration_date, 
        lc.customer_id as customer_id,
        lc.status as status, 
        c2.validation_code as validation_code, 
        c3.identity_document_number as identity_document_number 
        from linking_clients lc 
        LEFT JOIN customer c1 ON lc.customer_id = c1.customer_id 
        LEFT JOIN customer c2 ON c1.customer_id = c2.validation_code;"
```

Comment: Nos ayudaría bastante que modificaras la pregunta añadiendo el dataset (phpMyAdmin, Exportar) y, para esos datos de muestra, nos dijeras qué te gustaría obtener con una tabla de resultados, además de las explicaciones del significado de cada campo.

Comment: Agradezco tu comentario, he realizado tus sugerencias, editando la publicación. Trate  ser lo mas clara posible, pero si tienes sugerencias adicionales, házmelas saber por favor. y de ante mano gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque nos faltan unos datos de muestra y el resultado que esperas para ellos, te puedo adelantar algunos errores de sintaxis relacionados con los nombres de las tablas. Espero que te resulte útil.

```
SELECT lc.id as id, 
  lc.registration_date as registration_date, 
  lc.customer_id as customer_id,
  lc.status as status, 
  c2.validation_code as validation_code,
  c2.identity_document_number as identity_document_number 
  from oc_linking_clients lc 
  LEFT JOIN oc_customer c1 ON lc.customer_id = c1.customer_id 
  LEFT JOIN oc_customer c2 ON c1.customer_id = c2.validation_code;
```

Sin el resultado que esperas que me aclararía un poco más la semántica, poco más puedo hacer. Modifica tu pregunta para poder continuar ayudándote. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Esto debería ser un comentario. saludos